# Sampling from a matrix of discrete probability distributions in Python without a loop

Tags: python, random

I have a numpy array `P` with size `(N,M)`, where each row is a discrete probability distribution over `0, ..., M -1` (i.e. each row sums to one and all elements are non-negative). I also have an array `x` with length `K` containing elements in `0, ..., N-1`. For each `x[k]`, my goal is to generate one sample according to distribution `P[x[k],  :]` and store them in array `y` with length `K`.

I have written a code for this task with a loop

```
y = np.zeros(K)
for i, k in enumerate(K):
    y[i] = np.random.choice(np.arange(M), p = P[x[k],:])
```

Is it possible to compute `y` without using a loop?